# AS3 : displaying multiple (unlimited) achievements for 2 seconds each

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs4

I'm working on a very simple (1st project) "game" with various achievements. In fact, that's pretty much all there is to the game.

Let's say we have 3 possible achievements:

- Game started
- You played 5 seconds
- You played 6 seconds.

(I know, I know, I can hear you: Wow, looks like a super fun game concept ! hehe)

I'm trying to build a generic function in charge of displaying the achievement message on the screen, and remove it 2 seconds after it had been displayed. It mean multiple achievement can be displayed at the same time. But each should disapear after their own 2 seconds.

I tried to instanciate a new timer for each achievement whitout success. The problem is that each time need a name, and a callback function, and I have no way to link a timer to an achievement message since I have to use the callback function.
I'm sure I'm just doing it wrong since it's my first project, so I'm asking for some help.

Here's the code I have to display an achievement:

```
var genericTimer:Array = new Array();
function displayAchievement(msg){
    var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();    
    myTextBox.text = msg;
    myTextBox.x = 50;    
    myTextBox.y = 20; 
    addChild(myTextBox);

    genericTimer[] = new Timer(2000, 1);
    //Make myTextBox (of this instance only) disapear after 2 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by the help of anonymous function. Personally I don't like them, but such approach will give you minimum of code:

```
function displayAchievement(msg:String):void {
    var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();
    myTextBox.text = msg;
    myTextBox.x = 50;
    myTextBox.y = 20;
    addChild(myTextBox);

    var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function (e:TimerEvent):void {
        removeChild(myTextBox);
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Woo ! Thanks ! Didn't know AS was supporting anonymous functions.
Exactly what I was looking for.
Out of curiosity, how would YOU do it without an anonymous function

Comment: @FMaz008 Be careful with anonymous functions in AS3. If not handled properly, they are a huge source of memory leaks. In general, it is recommended to just not use them at all in favor of passing a function normally (and, in my opinion, they make for extremely poor OOP structure, even if they do solve your problem)

Answer (score 2):

I would personally do it using an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` handler.

```
const TIME_TO_DISPLAY_ACHIEVEMENTS:uint = 2000; //ms
var achievements:Vector.<Object> = new Vector.<Object>();
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

function displayAchievement(msg){
    var myTextBox:TextField = new TextField();    
    myTextBox.text = msg;
    myTextBox.x = 50;    
    myTextBox.y = 20; 
    addChild(myTextBox);

    achievements.push({tf:myTextBox, time:getTimer()});
}

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    var i:uint, l:uint, t:uint;
    t = getTimer();
    l = achievements.length;
    for (i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (achievements[i].time + TIME_TO_DISPLAY_ACHIEVEMENTS <= t) {
            removeChild(achievements[i].tf);
            achievements.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

That's untested and I wrote it pretty quickly, so you may need to alter it to make it compile and/or run.

Basically, you add an object with the achievement and a timestamp to a Vector or array. Then on each frame, you quickly cycle backward (to account for removing objects) through and check if any have expired. If they have, you remove them from the stage and from the vector/array.

This could definitely be optimized and you could replace ENTER_FRAME with a Timer that runs every 100ms or something to save on CPU time, but it should work

Comment: While it's a little more than I asked, I believe this is the best answer from a technical perspective.

Comment: removeChild(achievements[i]); should be removeChild(achievements[i].tf);

Comment: And while you mentionned it was somewhat a draft, it seems this method use 100% CPU and make the movie crash (?)...

Comment: It really shouldn't be running at 100% CPU. It's a simple loop that, unless you have 5000 achievements being added every frame, shouldn't be an issue. Are you sure the achievements are being removed? Also, make sure this is only added once. If you are adding it in a class that is added multiple times, it is redundant. Also, at the end of the handler, add `trace(achievements.length)`. Let's make sure the achievements are actually being removed from the vector.